# MySql Query taking too long for bulk amount of records

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query

```
   SELECT IF(g.id !="",g.image,p.products_image) products_image
        , p.products_date_added
        , IF(g.id !="", CONCAT(pd.products_name, " - ",g.image_caption),pd.products_name) products_name
        , p.production_status
        , p.customers_id
        , p.products_quantity
        , g.id g_id
        , p.ean as pean
        , g.ean as gean
        , p.products_id
        , p.manufacturers_id
        , p.products_price
        , p.products_tax_class_id
        , IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) specials_new_products_price
        , IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) final_price 
     FROM products_description pd
        , products p 
     LEFT 
     JOIN gemstone_combination_images g 
       ON g.products_id = p.products_id 
     LEFT 
     JOIN manufacturers m 
       ON p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id 
     LEFT 
     JOIN specials_retail_prices s 
       ON p.products_id = s.products_id
        , products_to_categories p2c
    WHERE p.products_status = 1 
      AND p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
      AND pd.products_id = p2c.products_id 
      AND pd.language_id = 1
```

[image]

currently this query return me more than 14k records and take almost 1 minute to execute. In future as the number records increase it will take even more loading time. So can someone suggest me anything in my query to optimize it ?

Thanks

Comment: well, 14k records are not a little. do you have indizes on your tables?

Comment: Do not tag unnecessary attributes. Your database is sql or mysql. It is not related to php also.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yes I can understand the number of records I am fetching and Yes I have made few indices as well otherwise it was taking more than 1 min. More specifically I need a suggestion for future perspective when the records are doubled than the current numbers after 6 months or so

Comment: can you describe your structure? there are different ways to solve this issue, but dependent on where are you in your project. if you can change db design (I don't think so, because you have 14k data) you have to change your approach of course, but if your software is lunched you can use store procedures and views to solve your problem too. I need more information about your structure for help.

Comment: This query should not take 1 minute if it returns 14k rows (which means you have only a handful of rows in each table). Please add your indexes or at least `explain`: write `explain ` infront of your `select` and post the result. How did you measure the time?

Comment: @Solarflare I have edited my question. Please have a look at the image and suggest your views
thanks

Comment: It would be much nicer if you could copy the EXPLAIN as text - but it appears there's no index on emstone_combination_images.product_id

Comment: Don't use comma join syntax, and definitely don't mix it with regular join syntax.